# Function in Django Model class not taking self argument?

Tags: python, django

I get a "TypeError: get_query() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" on the following code:

```
class graph_column_format(models.Model):

    def get_query(self):
        return self.graph_id.query_id   

    graph_id = models.ForeignKey("graph", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    column = models.ForeignKey("query_column", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               limit_choices_to={"query_id": get_query()})
```

The definition is within the class so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only able to call the method if you have an instance of that model class like

```
< graph_column_format instance >.get_query()
```

But There's no way to use limit_choices_to in that way, but you can add the filter in modelForm constructor like,

Assuming you have query_id field on graph_column_format model

```
class graph_column_format_form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['query_id'].queryset = graph_column_format.objects.filter(query_id=self.instance.graph_id.query_id)
```